# How do you wrap a span in a checkboxlistfor control?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I am using the `CheckBoxListFor` MVC Helper and I would like to wrap a span around the text.

This is what I am currently getting:

`<label><input name="CustomForm.SelectedQualifications" type="checkbox" value="1">Secondary qualifications</label>`

I would like to get:

`<label><input name="CustomForm.SelectedQualifications" type="checkbox" value="1">`**<span>**`Secondary qualifications`**</span>**`</label>`

Code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.CustomForm.SelectedQualifications, Model.CustomForm.QualificationsV2)
```

Comment: do you want to apply with jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by applying short `jQuery` Script like below:

```
$('label').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).contents().eq(1).wrap('<span class="checkbox-span"/>')
});
```

Please checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/14zwmo35/3/).

https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/14zwmo35/3/

Hope it will helps you.